# Dart syntax of ".."

Tags: dart

I have a question in Dart, as follows:

```
void main() {
  String originUrl = "http://www.123.com?name={0}&age={1}";
  String newUrl = originUrl.replaceFirst('{0}', 'Jack')
    ..replaceFirst('{1}', '20');
  print(newUrl);
}
```

output:

```
http://www.123.com?name=Jack&age={1}
```

Why not below：

```
http://www.123.com?name=Jack&age=20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you don't need to use the [cascade operator](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-), using that you won't get the `String` returned by `replaceFirst('{1}', '20')`.

it should look like this:

```
  // Replace {0} with Jack, and return a new String
  String newUrl = originUrl.replaceFirst('{0}', 'Jack')
    .replaceFirst('{1}', '20'); //Replace {1} with 20 in the last string and return a new String.
```